# where are the point clouds saved when using the Constructor app?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm using the Constructor app and after I have scanned a room, I can't seem to find the saved point cloud anywhere on the device. I don't want to use the "Share" button, I would like to know where the data is saved locally. Would it be possible to know where the point clouds are saved on the device?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Lenovo Phab Pro and the scanned data of te Constructor app are saved in the following folder : **/sdcard/TangoConstructor/** as a .zip folder for each scene you captured. Inside, you should find your mesh as a .obj file.

It is not a raw point cloud that is saved but you can get the point cloud from the .obj file.

After the capture, it can takes several minutes for the app to process the mesh, you get a notification when it is done. Then, if you wait some minutes you should get a notification telling you where the data have been exported. Only after that you can access the target folder, it is not visible beforehand.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you happen to have a rooted phone? Do you find the .zip immediately in the folder you mentioned without even trying to share? Do you find the .zip files of all the rooms you've recorded previously?

Thank you very much

Comment: @Ilaria Actually I just scanned a second room and now the folder is not visible anymore, like for you.. Last time, I got a notification telling me where the files had been saved after the mesh was finished processing but not anymore. I have no idea why, i'll tell you if I find anything..
My phone is not rooted and one .zip file was created for each captured scene.

Comment: @Ilaria Alright I finally got the following notification "Exported to /sdcard/TangoConstructor/20171114121525. And this folder is accessible again. 

I guess it takes some seconds for the mesh to be exported in this folder after it has been processed and the folder is unreadable in the meanwhile. I'm editing my answer.